# Positioning scrollable content under fixed flexbox navigation menu

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I have the following snippet (need to view in full screen mode), that I'm trying to place the `<main>` element directly under the `<header>` element.  I have the `<header>` in a fixed position because I want it to stay at the top of the screen as the user scrolls through the content in the `<main>` element.  I've tried everything I know, but the best I can come up with is having the `<header>` element placed on top of the `<main>` element, which cuts off a big chunk of the content.

The closest possible solution I've come up with is putting a guesstimated top padding on the `<main>` element so it will clear the `<header>`.  However, this solution doesn't account for various screen sizes very well, since I'm using rem sizing instead of px.  The top padding idea gets even worse when placing several elements inside the `<header>` that use relative or percentage based height.  On one screen size everything may line up perfect, and on a different screen size the content can be way off.

Lastly, I know I can use jQuery to set the top padding dynamically, but it doesn't always seem to work that well.  Wondering is there's a pure css/html solution.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?  Is my top padding method the only workable solution?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navToggle').click(function() {
    $("div#bottom-container > nav").slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
      if(window.innerWidth >= "751") {
          $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").show();
      }else {
          $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").hide();
      }
  });

  $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
     if (window.innerWidth <= "750") {
       if ($(this).siblings().size() > 0) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow");
      }
    }
  });

   $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li").hover(function() {
        if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
          if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
            $(this).children("nav").stop().show();
         }
       }
     },function(){
       if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
         if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
           $(this).children("nav").hide();
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  :root {
    font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - .48rem) * 1.389));
  }
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Arial;
  height: auto !important;
}

#head-wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}
#second-wrap{
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
}
main{
  height:4000px;
  position:relative;
  padding-top:13rem;
}

header{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:200rem;
}

#navToggle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:999;
  height: 2.6rem;
}

#navToggle>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding-top:.9rem;
}

#bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

#bottom-container>nav {
  background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
  display: none;
  flex: 1;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  padding: 1.3rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

#bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  margin-bottom:10rem;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
}

/*
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////   THIS IS THE ONLY FIX I KNOW OF  //////////
*/
main{
  padding-top:5rem;
}
/*
////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/

/* Medium screens */
@media all and (min-width: 751px) {
  header{
    overflow-y:visible;
    overflow-x:visible;
    padding-bottom:0;
  }

  #navToggle {
    display: none;
  }

  #bottom-container {
    background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
    width: 100%;
    border-top: calc(5vh + 2vw) solid yellow;
  }

  #bottom-container>nav {
    display: block;
  }

  #bottom-container>nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 3rem;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li {
    position: static;
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a {
   padding: 0;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  #bottom-container >nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li{
    line-height: 2.5rem;
  }
  #bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav {
    margin-top:-194.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="head-wrap">
  <div id="second-wrap">
    <header>
      <div id="navToggle"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
      <div id='bottom-container'>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
            <li class="sub1">
              <a href="#">ITEM TWO <span class="toggle">Expand</span></a>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>

<main>
  <p>content top not visible but should be able to see</P>
  <p>line 1</P>
  <p>line 2</P>
  <p>line 3</P>
  <p>line 4</P>
  <p>line 5</P>
  <p>line 6</P>
  <p>line 7</P>
  <p>line 8</P>
  <p>line 9</P>
  <p>line 10</P>
    <p>line 11</P>
    <p>line 12</P>
    <p>line 13</P>
    <p>line 14</P>
    <p>line 15</P>
    <p>line 16</P>
    <p>line 17</P>
    <p>line 18</P>
    <p>line 19</P>
    <p>line 20</P>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on full screen the main already under the header but not in mobile

Comment: That's because of the padding-top placed on the `main` element.  Clunky, but it kind of works.  Wondering if there a better solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want this is pic after disable yellow border https://ibb.co/bR0YykQ can you take a screen shoot

Comment: My example is a simplified version of my live version.  In my live version there are several flex elements in my `<header>` element that all use either percentage or  relative heights.  This makes adding a fixed top pad to the `<main>` element almost useless.  The `<main>` element may line up fine on one screen size and be way off on another.  Looks like jQuery may be my only solution here with a css top pad back-up on the `<main>` element.

Comment: Did you try with CSS `position: sticky` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position instead of using JS ?

Comment: Inspect the height of the header, figure out the height of it and add a margin top to the main content?

Comment: @Arthur I did try `position: sticky` but couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: @Austin I solved with CSS by using sticky and answered. can you check? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made same result (correct me, if I'm wrong), but without js. And it seems, that whatever header height is considered by content below.

**The main idea** - not to wrap `<header>` and to apply to it `position: sticky`, `z-index` also not necessary.

I didn't use exactly your code, but tried to repeat the result. Hope you will find some useful ideas for your problem.

Some answers' code when screen width is small and toggle the menu, it pushs down main content. My code doesn't contain that issue.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
  
@media (min-width: 48rem) {
    :root {
        font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - .48rem) * 1.389));
    }
}
  
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Arial;
    height: auto !important;
 }

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

#navToggle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2.6rem;
}

#navToggle > a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    padding-top: .9rem;
}

#navToggle:hover + #bottom-container, #bottom-container:hover  {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#bottom-container {
    background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#bottom-container > nav  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#bottom-container > nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
}

#bottom-container > nav > ul li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;

}

#bottom-container nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
    padding: 1.3rem 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sub1 {
    position: relative;
}

.sub1 > nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sub1 > nav ul li {
    text-align: center;
}

.sub1 > a:hover + nav, .sub1 > a + nav:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    padding: 2px 8px;
}

main {
    height:4000px;
}

@media (min-width: 751px){
    #bottom-container > nav > ul {
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 3rem;
    }
    
    #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #bottom-container {
        height: 100%;
        border-top: calc(5vh + 2vw) solid yellow;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        position: static;
    }

    #navToggle {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="navToggle"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
            <div id='bottom-container'>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
                        <li class="sub1">
                            <a href="#">ITEM TWO <span class="toggle">Expand</span></a>
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        <li><a href="#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </header>


    <main>
        <p>content top not visible but should be able to see</P>
        <p>line 1</P>
        <p>line 2</P>
        <p>line 3</P>
        <p>line 4</P>
        <p>line 5</P>
        <p>line 6</P>
        <p>line 7</P>
        <p>line 8</P>
        <p>line 9</P>
        <p>line 10</P>
        <p>line 11</P>
        <p>line 12</P>
        <p>line 13</P>
        <p>line 14</P>
        <p>line 15</P>
        <p>line 16</P>
        <p>line 17</P>
        <p>line 18</P>
        <p>line 19</P>
        <p>line 20</P>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On small screens, when the header is grey, the main content scrolls in front of the header.

Comment: @thingEvery it is because of alpha channel in background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15); I took color from author's code

Answer (score 4):

This is sort of a rough hack, but you could create a second header which hides behind the real one which stays in the document flow and pushes down the `<main>`.

Just duplicate the elements that make up the header, give them a lower `z-index` and switch it from `position: fixed` to `position: relative`. Then just get rid of the height of the hidden `<header>` element and remove the `padding-top` from `<main>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navToggle').click(function() {
    $("div#bottom-container > nav").slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
      if(window.innerWidth >= "751") {
          $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").show();
      }else {
          $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").hide();
      }
  });

  $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
     if (window.innerWidth <= "750") {
       if ($(this).siblings().size() > 0) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow");
      }
    }
  });

   $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li").hover(function() {
        if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
          if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
            $(this).children("nav").stop().show();
         }
       }
     },function(){
       if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
         if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
           $(this).children("nav").hide();
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  :root {
    font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - .48rem) * 1.389));
  }
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Arial;
  height: auto !important;
}

#head-wrap,
#hidden-wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}
#hidden-wrap header {
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
}
#second-wrap{
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
}
#second-wrap2{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:998;
}

main{
  height:4000px;
  position:relative;
  /* padding-top:13rem; */
}

header{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:200rem;
}

#navToggle,
#navToggle2{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:999;
  height: 2.6rem;
}

#navToggle>a,
#navToggle2>a{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding-top:.9rem;
}

#bottom-container,
#bottom-container2{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

#bottom-container>nav,
#bottom-container2>nav{
  background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
  display: none;
  flex: 1;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul,
#bottom-container2 nav>ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li,
#bottom-container2 nav>ul>li{
  position: relative;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a,
#bottom-container2 nav>ul>li>a{
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  padding: 1.3rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle,
#bottom-container2 nav>ul>li>a span.toggle{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

#bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav,
#bottom-container2>nav>ul>li>nav{
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  margin-bottom:10rem;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
}

/*
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////   THIS IS THE ONLY FIX I KNOW OF  //////////
*/
main{
  /*padding-top:5rem;*/
}
/*
////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/

/* Medium screens */
@media all and (min-width: 751px) {
  header{
    overflow-y:visible;
    overflow-x:visible;
    padding-bottom:0;
  }

  #navToggle,
  #navToggle2{
    display: none;
  }

  #bottom-container,
  #bottom-container2{
    background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
    width: 100%;
    border-top: calc(5vh + 2vw) solid yellow;
  }

  #bottom-container>nav,
  #bottom-container2>nav{
    display: block;
  }

  #bottom-container>nav>ul,
  #bottom-container2>nav>ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 3rem;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li,
  #bottom-container2 nav>ul>li{
    position: static;
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a,
  #bottom-container2 nav>ul>li>a{
   padding: 0;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle,
  #bottom-container2 nav>ul>li>a span.toggle{
    display: none;
  }

  #bottom-container >nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li,
  #bottom-container2 >nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li{
    line-height: 2.5rem;
  }
  #bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav,
  #bottom-container2>nav>ul>li>nav{
    margin-top:-194.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="head-wrap">
  <div id="second-wrap">
    <header>
      <div id="navToggle"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
      <div id='bottom-container'>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
            <li class="sub1">
              <a href="#">ITEM TWO <span class="toggle">Expand</span></a>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="hidden-wrap">
  <div id="second-wrap2">
    <header>
      <div id="navToggle2"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
      <div id='bottom-container2'>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
            <li class="sub1">
              <a href="#">ITEM TWO <span class="toggle">Expand</span></a>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>

<main>
  <p>now you can see this text</p>
  <p>line 1</p>
  <p>line 2</p>
  <p>line 3</p>
  <p>line 4</p>
  <p>line 5</p>
  <p>line 6</p>
  <p>line 7</p>
  <p>line 8</p>
  <p>line 9</p>
  <p>line 10</p>
    <p>line 11</p>
    <p>line 12</p>
    <p>line 13</p>
    <p>line 14</p>
    <p>line 15</p>
    <p>line 16</p>
    <p>line 17</p>
    <p>line 18</p>
    <p>line 19</p>
    <p>line 20</p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I don't know why I didn't think of this before. Just set `#headwrap` and `<main>` to `position: relative`. Then, remove the `height` on `<main>` and set `<body>` to `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`. Finally, wrap the contents of `<main>` in a `<div>`.

Here, I've set the height of the div to 4000px to demonstrate the scrolling.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navToggle').click(function() {
    $("div#bottom-container > nav").slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
      if(window.innerWidth >= "751") {
          $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").show();
      }else {
          $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").hide();
      }
  });

  $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
     if (window.innerWidth <= "750") {
       if ($(this).siblings().size() > 0) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow");
      }
    }
  });

   $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li").hover(function() {
        if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
          if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
            $(this).children("nav").stop().show();
         }
       }
     },function(){
       if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
         if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
           $(this).children("nav").hide();
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  :root {
    font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - .48rem) * 1.389));
  }
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Arial;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#head-wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}

#second-wrap{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
}

main{
  /*height:4000px;*/
  position:relative;
  overflow: auto;
  /* padding-top:13rem; */
}

main>div {
  height: 4000px;
}

header{
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*height:200rem;*/
}

#navToggle{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:999;
  height: 2.6rem;
}

#navToggle>a{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding-top:.9rem;
}

#bottom-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

#bottom-container>nav{
  background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
  display: none;
  flex: 1;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li{
  position: relative;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a{
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  padding: 1.3rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

#bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav{
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  margin-bottom:10rem;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
}

/*
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////   THIS IS THE ONLY FIX I KNOW OF  //////////
*/
main{
  /*padding-top:5rem;*/
}
/*
////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/

/* Medium screens */
@media all and (min-width: 751px) {
  header{
    overflow-y:visible;
    overflow-x:visible;
    padding-bottom:0;
  }

  #navToggle{
    display: none;
  }

  #bottom-container{
    background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
    width: 100%;
    border-top: calc(5vh + 2vw) solid yellow;
  }

  #bottom-container>nav{
    display: block;
  }

  #bottom-container>nav>ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 3rem;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li{
    position: static;
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a{
   padding: 0;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle{
    display: none;
  }

  #bottom-container >nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li{
    line-height: 2.5rem;
  }
  #bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav{
    margin-top:-194.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="head-wrap">
  <div id="second-wrap">
    <header>
      <div id="navToggle"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
      <div id='bottom-container'>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
            <li class="sub1">
              <a href="#">ITEM TWO <span class="toggle">Expand</span></a>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <li><a href="#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>


<main>
  <div>
  <p>now you can see this text</p>
  <p>line 1</p>
  <p>line 2</p>
  <p>line 3</p>
  <p>line 4</p>
  <p>line 5</p>
  <p>line 6</p>
  <p>line 7</p>
  <p>line 8</p>
  <p>line 9</p>
  <p>line 10</p>
    <p>line 11</p>
    <p>line 12</p>
    <p>line 13</p>
    <p>line 14</p>
    <p>line 15</p>
    <p>line 16</p>
    <p>line 17</p>
    <p>line 18</p>
    <p>line 19</p>
    <p>line 20</p>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the creative solution, but seems like code that Google wouldn't like very much.  Duplicate and hidden nav level content.  I was really hoping there was a positioning trick I simply didn't know of, but I'm starting to realize that a jQuery solution is the best way to go about this problem.  I'm going to leave the bounty open, just to see if there are any other solution available.  If nobody else comes forward, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Austin Yeah cool. I'm interested to see other solutions too.

Comment: @Austin I've updated my answer with a much better solution.

Answer (score 4):

Please remove first top two div containers of header element as there is no need to wrap header. header element is already container.

Please remove `height:200rem;` in header style and `padding-top: 13rem or 5rem` for main element's style.

Finally, please update header style's position property to [sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) instead of `absolute` and add z-index.

Below, I have tested it and updated codebase.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navToggle').click(function() {
    $("div#bottom-container > nav").slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
      if(window.innerWidth >= "751") {
          $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").show();
      }else {
          $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").hide();
      }
  });

  $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
     if (window.innerWidth <= "750") {
       if ($(this).siblings().size() > 0) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow");
      }
    }
  });

   $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li").hover(function() {
        if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
          if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
            $(this).children("nav").stop().show();
         }
       }
     },function(){
       if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
         if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
           $(this).children("nav").hide();
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  :root {
    font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - .48rem) * 1.389));
  }
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Arial;
  height: auto !important;
}

main{
  height:4000px;
  position:relative;
}

header{
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}

#navToggle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:999;
  height: 2.6rem;
}

#navToggle>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding-top:.9rem;
}

#bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

#bottom-container>nav {
  background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
  display: none;
  flex: 1;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  padding: 1.3rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

#bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  margin-bottom:10rem;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
}

/*
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////   THIS IS THE ONLY FIX I KNOW OF  //////////
*/
main{
  /* remove padding top */
}
/*
////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/

/* Medium screens */
@media all and (min-width: 751px) {
  header{
    overflow-y:visible;
    overflow-x:visible;
    padding-bottom:0;
  }

  #navToggle {
    display: none;
  }

  #bottom-container {
    background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
    width: 100%;
    border-top: calc(5vh + 2vw) solid yellow;
  }

  #bottom-container>nav {
    display: block;
  }

  #bottom-container>nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 3rem;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li {
    position: static;
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a {
   padding: 0;
  }

  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  #bottom-container >nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li{
    line-height: 2.5rem;
  }
  #bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav {
    margin-top:-194.5rem;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <div id="navToggle"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
    <div id='bottom-container'>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
          <li class="sub1">
            <a href="#">ITEM TWO <span class="toggle">Expand</span></a>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <li><a href="#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>content top not visible but should be able to see</P>
    <p>line 1</P>
    <p>line 2</P>
    <p>line 3</P>
    <p>line 4</P>
    <p>line 5</P>
    <p>line 6</P>
    <p>line 7</P>
    <p>line 8</P>
    <p>line 9</P>
    <p>line 10</P>
      <p>line 11</P>
      <p>line 12</P>
      <p>line 13</P>
      <p>line 14</P>
      <p>line 15</P>
      <p>line 16</P>
      <p>line 17</P>
      <p>line 18</P>
      <p>line 19</P>
      <p>line 20</P>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
 Run code snippet
```

Comment: On small screens, when the header is grey, the main content scrolls in front of the header.

Comment: Because there was background opacity set in navToggle element of the header. To fix it, you could just remove that opacity.

Answer (score 0):

> A simple fix, i used `padding` in `%` rather then `rem` or `px`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navToggle').click(function() {
    $("div#bottom-container > nav").slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
      $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").show();
    } else {
      $("header > div#bottom-container > nav").hide();
    }
  });

  $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth <= "750") {
      if ($(this).siblings().size() > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow");
      }
    }
  });

  $("header > div#bottom-container > nav > ul > li").hover(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
      if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
        $(this).children("nav").stop().show();
      }
    }
  }, function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= "751") {
      if ($(this).children("nav").size() > 0) {
        $(this).children("nav").hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
   :root {
    font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - .48rem) * 1.389));
  }
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Arial;
  height: auto !important;
}

#head-wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#second-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

main {
  height: 4000px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 13rem;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200rem;
}

#navToggle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2.6rem;
}

#navToggle>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding-top: .9rem;
}

#bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

#bottom-container>nav {
  background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
  display: none;
  flex: 1;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  padding: 1.3rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

#bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li>a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
}


/*
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////   Use padding in %  //////////
*/

main {
  padding-top: 11%;
}

@media (max-width:1200px) {
  main {
  padding-top: 12.5%;
}
}

@media (max-width:1023px) {
 main {
  padding-top: 14.5%;
}
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  main {
  padding-top: 8%;
}
}


/*
////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/


/* Medium screens */

@media all and (min-width: 751px) {
  header {
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: visible;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  #navToggle {
    display: none;
  }
  #bottom-container {
    background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
    width: 100%;
    border-top: calc(5vh + 2vw) solid yellow;
  }
  #bottom-container>nav {
    display: block;
  }
  #bottom-container>nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 3rem;
  }
  #bottom-container nav>ul>li {
    position: static;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  #bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li {
    line-height: 2.5rem;
  }
  #bottom-container>nav>ul>li>nav {
    margin-top: -194.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="head-wrap">
    <div id="second-wrap">
      <header>
        <div id="navToggle"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
        <div id='bottom-container'>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
              <li class="sub1">
                <a href="#">ITEM TWO <span class="toggle">Expand</span></a>
                <nav>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <li><a href="#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>

  <main>
    <p>content top not visible but should be able to see</P>
    <p>line 1</P>
    <p>line 2</P>
    <p>line 3</P>
    <p>line 4</P>
    <p>line 5</P>
    <p>line 6</P>
    <p>line 7</P>
    <p>line 8</P>
    <p>line 9</P>
    <p>line 10</P>
    <p>line 11</P>
    <p>line 12</P>
    <p>line 13</P>
    <p>line 14</P>
    <p>line 15</P>
    <p>line 16</P>
    <p>line 17</P>
    <p>line 18</P>
    <p>line 19</P>
    <p>line 20</P>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If the window is around 900px wide, the top line still gets cut off.

Comment: @thingEvery Updated my ans using `media-quires` ill manage to adjust the padding now its working fine please check and do let me know

Comment: This is better, but some text still gets cut off between 751px and 767px. Plus, OP stated "The top padding idea gets even worse when placing several elements inside the <header> that use relative or percentage based height." I'd probably just go the jQuery route, but outside of that, creating a bunch of media queries is probably his only real option - as long as the elements in his header are not going to change.

Comment: I just created the quries which were mostly use by device he can change that accordingly or use one more query between 700 to 767. n second i agree with you, in generally header should be fixed height and due to which we got so many options to correct the position of content correctly else Jquery is the only option to play with as you mention that......

Answer (score 0):

aren't you looking for [position: sticky; top: 0;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) ? You want to have menu which follows user when he scrolls right? Then try to change **#bottom-container** to:

```
#bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

And I think that's it. But one is for sure - you need to rethink how you created all this structure cuz it's messy as hell. You could get the same results with:

html:

```
<header>
    <nav id="mobileMenu"><a href="#">Menu</a></nav>
    <nav id='menu'>
      <div class="menuItem">
        <a href="#">ITEM ONE</a>
      </div>
      <div class="bigMenuItem">
        HOVER ME
        <div class="menuItemsCon">
          <div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></div>
          <div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></div>
          <div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></div>
          <div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label class="bigMenuItem" for="inputClick">
        CLICK ME
        <input type="checkbox" name="input" id="inputClick" style="display:none;">
        <div class="menuItemsCon click">
          <div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></div>
          <div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></div>
          <div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></div>
          <div class="menuItem"><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>content top not visible but should be able to see</P>
    <p>line 1</P>
    <p>line 2</P>
    <p>line 3</P>
    <p>line 4</P>
    <p>line 5</P>
    <p>line 6</P>
    <p>line 7</P>
    <p>line 8</P>
    <p>line 9</P>
    <p>line 10</P>
  </main>
```

style.css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) {
  :root {
    font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - .48rem) * 1.389));
  }
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Arial;
  height: auto !important;
}
main{
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}

/*Changed classes*/

header{
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index: 1;
}

a{
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#mobileMenu{
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  height: 2.6rem
}

#mobileMenu a{
  color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  padding-top: .9rem;
}

#menu{
  background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
  border-top: calc(5vh + 2vw) solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:751px) {
  #mobileMenu{
    display: block;
  }
  #menu{
    display: none;
  }
}

#menu > .menuItem, #menu > .bigMenuItem{
  width: calc(100%/3);
  height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

#menu > .bigMenuItem{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu > .bigMenuItem .menuItemsCon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -100vh;
  transition: all .5s;
}


#menu > .bigMenuItem .menuItemsCon > .menuItem{
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

/* and if you want to click for submenu to show*/
#menu  .bigMenuItem input:checked + .menuItemsCon, #menu  .bigMenuItem:hover .menuItemsCon:not(.click){
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}
```

And no JS cuz if you don't have to don't use it. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you a Vanilla-JavaScript instead of jQuery …

Try to get the size of "header" when the page loads (onload event) and add it to the padding of "main":

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e){
  my_main.style.paddingTop = my_header.clientHeight + "px";
}, 1);
```

inorder to work I have given an "id" to the "header" and the "main" elements:

```
<header id="my_header"> <main id="my_main">
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(e){
  my_main.style.paddingTop = my_header.clientHeight + "px";
}, 1);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
  
@media (min-width: 48rem) {
    :root {
        font-size: calc(1rem + ((1vw - .48rem) * 1.389));
    }
}
  
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Arial;
    height: auto !important;
 }

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

#navToggle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2.6rem;
}

#navToggle > a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    padding-top: .9rem;
}

#navToggle:hover + #bottom-container, #bottom-container:hover  {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#bottom-container {
    background-color: rgb(250, 209, 14);
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#bottom-container > nav  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#bottom-container > nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
}

#bottom-container > nav > ul li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;

}

#bottom-container nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
    padding: 1.3rem 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sub1 {
    position: relative;
}

.sub1 > nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sub1 > nav ul li {
    text-align: center;
}

.sub1 > a:hover + nav, .sub1 > a + nav:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    padding: 2px 8px;
}

main {
    height:4000px;
}

@media (min-width: 751px){
    #bottom-container > nav > ul {
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 3rem;
    }
    
    #bottom-container nav>ul>li>a span.toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #bottom-container {
        height: 100%;
        border-top: calc(5vh + 2vw) solid yellow;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        position: static;
    }

    #navToggle {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header id="my_header">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="navToggle"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
            <div id='bottom-container'>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
                        <li class="sub1">
                            <a href="#">ITEM TWO <span class="toggle">Expand</span></a>
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        <li><a href="#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </header>


    <main id="my_main">
        <p>content top not visible but should be able to see</P>
        <p>line 1</P>
        <p>line 2</P>
        <p>line 3</P>
        <p>line 4</P>
        <p>line 5</P>
        <p>line 6</P>
        <p>line 7</P>
        <p>line 8</P>
        <p>line 9</P>
        <p>line 10</P>
        <p>line 11</P>
        <p>line 12</P>
        <p>line 13</P>
        <p>line 14</P>
        <p>line 15</P>
        <p>line 16</P>
        <p>line 17</P>
        <p>line 18</P>
        <p>line 19</P>
        <p>line 20</P>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```